# Unable to create working custom transformer

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native

As advised in https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/393#issuecomment-173247497,
I have created custom transformer but was unable to make it work.

Transformer:

```
var transformer = require('react-native/packager/transformer');
var fs = require("fs");

module.exports = function (data, callback) {
    if (data.filename.indexOf("index.android.js") !== -1) {
        callback({
            code: data.sourceCode,
            map: JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("./index.android.js.map").toString()),
            filename: data.filename
        })
    } else {
        transformer(data, callback);
    }
};
```

Repro:

- clone https://github.com/krtr/native-repro
- npm install
- react-native run-android
- react-native start
  --transformer `<absolute path to transformer.js>`
- tap `reload js` in phone/emulator

Comment: link to error: http://i.imgur.com/et6Bc5f.jpg